# matching query does not exist Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am programming in Django 1.4.3 with Python 2.7 on Windows Vista, making a website offering products. So I have various products listed in my `/productos` subpage. Now I am trying to display the page `/producto/#` that displays the page with with the product listed. Here is my `urls.py`, which acts like the index for my pages:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('demo.apps.home.views',
        url(r'^$','index_view', name = 'vista_principal'),
        url(r'^about/$','about_view', name = 'vista_about'),
        url(r'^productos/$','productos_view', name = 'vista_productos'),
        url(r'^producto/(?P<id_prod>.*)/$', 'singleProduct_view', 
            name = 'vista_single_producto'),
        url(r'^contacto/$','contacto_view', name = 'vista_contacto'),
        url(r'^login/$', 'login_view', name = 'vista_login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', 'logout_view', name = 'vista_logout'),
)
```

I also have a `singleProduct_view` function in my `views.py` that retrieves that product and feeds it to my website.

```
def singleProduct_view(request, id_prod):
        prod = producto.objects.get(id = id_prod)
        ctx = {'producto':prod}
        return render_to_reponse('home/SingleProducto.html', ctx, 
                                  context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

However, when I type `/producto/2', it gave me`producto matching query does not exist` error. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Try @Necrolyte2 answer

Comment: are you sure you have product id number 2?

Comment: Turns out that I had `render_to_reponse` instead of `render_to_response`. Left out the 's' in 'response'. Thanks to everyone to helped out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your url for the producto page as follows

```
url(r'^producto/(?P<id_prod>\d+)/$', 'singleProduct_view', 
        name = 'vista_single_producto')
```

It is likely that your regular expression .* was matching a string so that id_prod inside your singleProduct_view was actually a string not a digit

** Edit **

Then inside of your view you need to convert your id_prod to an integer

```
def singleProduct_view(request, id_prod):
        prod = producto.objects.get(id = int(id_prod))
        ctx = {'producto':prod}
        return render_to_reponse('home/SingleProducto.html', ctx, 
                                  context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

You could also utilize the get_object_or_404 to ensure that your object exists in the database as well.
That would change your view as such

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def singleProduct_view(request, id_prod):
        prod = get_object_or_404( producto, id = int(id_prod) )
        ctx = {'producto':prod}
        return render_to_reponse('home/SingleProducto.html', ctx, 
                                  context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: See updated answer as dusual was correct about the string/integer issue. For some reason I thought that django magically converted if the regex matched only a digit.
You will still want to use my regex though instead of .* as that will match anything they enter not just digits

Comment: Yes as I have mentioned @Necrolyte2 has suggested a better methodology would be to use \d+ and numbers but even that kind of gives implementation information to the user instead better still you can use slugs

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem could well be the fact that you are querying an Integerfield with a unicode string however changing the url as proposed may not help you get rid of the error . Because you will still get the argument as a string.

However , you should convert the argument id_prod to int and also make sure you do have an entity in the database with id = 2